# undefined keyword error in pycharm robot framework

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework

i am using pycharm with intellibot and robot framework plugins. one of a sudden, keywords turned undefined like "click element". but other robot framework libraries works well.

```java
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: getComponentAdapterOfType is used to get com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl (requestorClass=com.millennialmedia.intellibot.psi.RobotPsiManager, requestorConstructor=public com.millennialmedia.intellibot.psi.RobotPsiManager(com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl)).

Probably constructor should be marked as NonInjectable. [Plugin: com.millennialmedia.intellibot]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorParameterResolver.findTargetAdapter(ConstructorParameterResolver.kt:111)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorParameterResolver.resolveInstance(ConstructorParameterResolver.kt:59)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.kt:505)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:35)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:110)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:72)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:65)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.kt:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:295)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.convertAndLoadProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:624)
    at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.prepareProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:315)
    at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.lambda$openExistingProject$0(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:241)
    at com.intellij.platform.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$1$1.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:247)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$4(ApplicationImpl.java:441)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.lambda$underThreadNameRunnable$3(ConcurrencyUtil.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Have you updated any version? There is seems to be a similar bug report here: [om.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: getComponentAdapterOfType in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3](https://github.com/millennialmedia/intellibot/issues/226)

Comment: What version of `SeleniumLibrary` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellibot plugin exception still continue, but I fixed undefined keyword problem by installing "IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched" plugin.

Answer (score 6):

**I am facing same issue but it got resolved by the following steps.**

1. Go to https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot/blob/develop/intellibot.jar
2. Download the jar file
3. Open PyCharm -> Settings -> Plugins -> Click on Setting Icon (Right side from the Installed tab) -> Select Install plugin from Disk
4. Import the jar file in PyCharm editor
5. Click on Restart

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too late, but here we go

I faced the same issue. additionally, pycharm wasn't recognizing some of the keywords.

1. My plug-in was version IntelliBot 0.***10***.143.381 (pycharm plugin marketplace)
2. On Intellibot GitHub the latest version is 0.***13***.191.8026

So.

1. I uninstall the old plugin.
2. Download the release version on Github
   https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot/releases/tag/v0.13.191.8026
3. Install the new version

Now everything is working, no more error notifications and no more problems with the syntax highlight